# Optimizing $(X_{n}+c)^{2}$ to show that $P(\overline{X}_{n}\geq \lambda) \leq E(X_{n}^{2})/(EX_{n}^{2}+ \lambda^{2})$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales

Define $\overline{X}_{n}:=\max\limits_{1\leq m \leq n} X_{m}$ and let $(X_{n})_{n}$ be a martingale where $X_{0}:=0$ and $EX_{n}^{2}< \infty$

Show that $P(\overline{X}_{n}\geq \lambda) \leq E(X_{n}^{2})/(EX_{n}^{2}+ \lambda^{2})$

As a hint: Consider $(X_{n}+c)^{2}$ and optimize over $c$.

It is clear that $((X_{n}+c)^{2})_{n}$ is a submartingale and when I optimize over $c$, I get:

$X_{n}^{2}+2X_{n}c +c^{2}\Rightarrow 0=2X_{n}+2c=0\Rightarrow -X_{n}=c$

It is also clear I need to use Doob's inequality but I am not sure how to go about this, and how the above optimization helps me.

Answer (score 1):

First observe that for a non-negative $c$, 
$$
\Pr\left(\bar{X_n}\geqslant\lambda\right)\leqslant \Pr\left(\max_{1\leqslant m\leqslant n}\left(X_m+c\right)^2\geqslant \left(\lambda+c\right)^2\right);
$$
apply Doob's inequality to get a control of the latter probability by a term involving $\mathbb E\left[\left(X_n+c\right)^2\right]$. This leads to a bound of $\Pr\left(\bar{X_n}\geqslant\lambda\right)$ valid for every non-negative $c$, namely, 
$$
\Pr\left(\max_{1\leqslant m\leqslant n}\left(X_m+c\right)^2\geqslant \left(\lambda+c\right)^2\right)\leqslant \frac1{\left(\lambda+c\right)^2}\mathbb E\left[\left(X_n+c\right)^2\right]=:f(c).$$ Then optimize $f(c)$ over $c$.

Comment: When I optimize as above, I get $c=-X_{n}$

Comment: Your $c$ should not be random.

Comment: What am I doing incorrectly? My understanding was to simply find $c$ that fulfills $\frac{\partial}{\partial c} X_{n}^{2}+2X_{n}c+c^{2}=0$. This then implies $c=-X_{n}$?

Comment: @SABOY I have added some details in the answer in order to clarify the optimization step.

Comment: Never differentiated on $\mathbb E$ before but I assume $\frac{\partial}{\partial c}\mathbb E[(X_{n}+c)^{2}]=(X_{n}+c)^{2}$?

Comment: Actually $\mathbb E\left[\left(X_n+c\right)^2\right]$ is a polynomial of degree $2$ in $c$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo you need to put in a constraint of $c >=0$ for your first observation to stand. SABOY, note $c$ should be treat as a varying constant (still a variable, but not a r.v.), and $\mathbb E[(X_{n}+c)^{2}]$ is simply $\mathbb E(X_{n}^2) + c^{2}$ where $E(X_{n}^2)$ is a constant. You can simply take derivative to minimize $\frac{E(X_{n}^2) + c^2}{(\lambda + c)^2}$ which gives you $c=\frac{E(X_{n}^2)}{\lambda}$.