# Exercise with Doob's inequality (looks similar to kolmogorov inequality)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, martingales

Let $S_n= X_1+\ldots X_n$ where $X_i$ are independent, with mean $0$ and finite variance (possibly not the same). Let $F_n$ be the natural filtration generated by the $X_i$.

a) Prove that for $c>0$ $(S_n+c)^2$ is a submartingale.

b) Using (a) and Doob's inequality show that for $x>0$ 
$$
\mathbb{P}\Bigl( \max_{1\leq m\leq n}S_m \geq x \Bigr) \leq \frac{\operatorname{var}(S_n)}{\operatorname{var}(S_n) +x^2}.
$$

I have proved (a) (even though I don't see why $c>0$ is needed) butI don't know how to prove (b), especially because I don't see where $var(S_n)$ at the denominator comes from. This looks like Kolmogorov inequality but we don't have the absolute value for $S_n$ so we have a sharper bound.

Comment: thanks i have edited it

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3378193/36150)

Comment: Thank you I'm really bad at looking for duplicates :/